# jQuery slideDown, and slideUp NOT animate

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't explain why my **slideUp** and **slideDown** is not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="text-center">
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success" type="button" id="show">Show</button>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" type="button" id="hide">Hide</button>
    </div>

    <br><br><br>

    <table class="table table-striped table-dark">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">First</th>
                <th scope="col">Last</th>
                <th scope="col">Handle</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">1</th>
                <td>Mark</td>
                <td>Otto</td>
                <td>@mdo</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">2</th>
                <td>Jacob</td>
                <td>Thornton</td>
                <td>@fat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">3</th>
                <td>Larry</td>
                <td>the Bird</td>
                <td>@twitter</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <!-- EX1 -->
    <!-- $('#hide').on('click', function() { -->
    <!-- $('table').hide(); -->
    <!-- }); -->
    <!-- $('#show').on('click', function() { -->
    <!-- $('table').show(); -->
    <!-- }); -->
    <!-- EX2 -->
    <!-- $('#hide').on('click',function() { -->
    <!-- $('table').fadeOut(2000); -->
    <!-- }); -->
    <!-- $('#show').on('click',function() { -->
    <!-- $('table').fadeIn(2000); -->
    <!-- }); -->

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $('#hide').on('click', function() {
            $('.table').slideUp("slow", function(){
                console.log('%c -------->> hide clicked <<--------', "color: green;");
            });
        });

        $('#show').on('click', function() {
            $('.table').slideDown("slow", function(){
                console.log('%c -------->> show clicked <<--------', "color: green;");
            });

        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I can reproduce it here too

https://jsfiddle.net/bheng/gef1ntLq/

I've tried almost every version of jQuery.

Comment: Can you provide a link to a working example of what you're trying to do or a reference as to what you're trying to achieve, maybe a link to the doc's example or api reference

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/slideUp/

Answer (score 1):

Tables can be picky and you should not use any animation effects on the table directly. But it works fine, if you pack the table into a div and use `slideUp()` and `slideDown()` on the div.

Here is an updated version of your [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kacjsrh6/).

Comment: Glad, that I could help. If this answered your question, then please choose it as the accepted answer.